# Understanding Similarities Between Staging and Production Servers

Tags: deployment, devops, configuration-management

I'm curious about the reasons behind making a staging server closely resemble a production server. In many development environments, I've noticed that the staging server is often configured similarly to the production server. I'd like to gain insights into why this practice is common and what advantages it offers.

Comment: If the staging server _didn't_ closely resemble the production server, what would be the point of it?!